# Qt Build for android-19

Tags: android, qt, qt5, cross-compiling

I'm using Qt `5.15` for creating an application.

The kit for android exists and is set to `android-29` and everything works fine. But I have a old device that is running android `4.4.4` so I need to use `android-19` platform. I download the platform and it is selectable inside the `build` menu in the `Build & Run`.

From my understanding it should be able to compile using Qt `5.15` or do I need to go lower?

Using:
NDK: `r21`

This is the compiler error:

```
> Task :processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     D:\App-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_arm64_v8a_x86_x86_64_Clang_Qt_5_15_0_for_Android-Debug\android-build\AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-81:19: AAPT: error: attribute android:extractNativeLibs not found.
         
     D:\App-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_arm64_v8a_x86_x86_64_Clang_Qt_5_15_0_for_Android-Debug\android-build\AndroidManifest.xml:21:9-79:20: AAPT: error: 'orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density' is incompatible with attribute configChanges (attr) flags [locale=4, mcc=1, mnc=2, touchscreen=8, keyboard=16, keyboardHidden=32, navigation=64, orientation=128, screenLayout=256, uiMode=512, screenSize=1024, smallestScreenSize=2048, layoutDirection=8192, fontScale=1073741824].
```

Answer (score 2):

After some tinkering I finally got it to compile. I will leave this as the answer so it might help anyone else.

As the errors above said, some of the attributes in the manifest did not work, so I removed `attribute android:extractNativeLibs` and `android:configChanges`. If you already had the android folder created by Qt Creator, delete it and generate it again, and then remove those above.

After this, it complained about using new java features. So I downloaded Qt `5.12.10` and used this kit instead.

Also don't forget to change all of the imports to be `5.12` inside the `.qml` files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer save me after fails of 3 days. Now I can build APK.

Comment: Although removing the attribute android:configChanges solves the problems of not compiling but cause your app not to respond to changes in android device , specially the orientation.
But using the latest Android build SDK , is a better solution, for example Android Build SDK 31